# Text box clears while showing error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two controls. Both are mandatory. I have used this code in the controller

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReportName))
    {
           if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
           {
                  ViewData["Error"] = "Errortext.";
                  return View(model);
           }
                  ViewData["Error"] = "Errortext.";
    }
```

This is only for failure scenario and I have some other code for success scenario. I am validating this on a button click. User should enter both the textbox and press the button. But when one is entered and the button is clicked, The error message is shown. But the values entered in the textbox gets cleared. Can any one suggest

Comment: you are not returning model back to view

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this if it helps you?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReportName))
{
       if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
       {
              ViewData["Error"] = "Errortext.";
              return View(model);
       }
       ViewData["Error"] = "Errortext.";
       return View(model);
}
```